How to setup Android Studio for Nexus proxy
At our company we have Nexus proxy but we can't get it to work. We use Maven and as I look at the documentation in Android Studio we need two repositories for this to work (Maven Central and Google Maven). The Admin guy does not know how to set this up. I looked in the .m2 directory and read you must put a settings.xml file in it to make it work with Nexus proxy. I really like to know what is the format for this so that we can work with this proxy. So can somebody please show me an Example of this so I can use this as a template. Maybe I am on the wrong path, please can somebody direct me in the right direction?

Does this answer your question? Add Maven repository to build.gradle

I already have a link in my gradle.build to the Nexus proxy but thats not enough. We don't need credentials because we are on a Windows plaform with SSO. We can connect to the proxy but the Maven repositories can't be loaded.

The problem is probably that Gradle I don't think supports any kind of SSO in the free version, you need to be using the Enterprise Gradle version I think for SSO authentication. I think that the only workable method is Basic Auth over HTTPS (It was when I ran a Nexus Server, some time ago). Therefore a correctly configured Nexus Server and setting a user/password is required. At least trying the simplest method of connecting will narrow down the problem.
